# how to dispatch payload to reducer and update the Initial state object

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch, reducers

I am trying to dispatch a payload with multiple properties and values to reducer

my dispatcher Component like:

```
 class Example extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
     {//here i have a form to submit name and value}
    </React.Fragment>
   );
  } 
 }
 const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'NINJA', payload: { name: 'aaaa', value: 5 } });
   }
  };
 export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Example);
```

my reducer:

```
const intialstate = {}

const reducer = (state = intialstate, action) => {
  console.log("inside reducer");
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'NINJA':
        return {
            ...state,
            name: action.payload.name,
            value: action.payload.value
        }
  };

  return state;


}
export default reducer;
```

once the action is deispatched i get an error saying :

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

and help me to get the complete object "initialState" with properties like name and value into another component where am displaying them.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to give you an adequate answer without making wild assumptions about your code. You've included the reducer and your `mapDispatchToProps` function, but the error is occurring in your component's render function. Please include the relevant component as well as the file where you create your store.

Comment: guide me if am wrong, as i understood redux reducers. after a action dispatch we do some update to store based on action type in switch case and return it and here am getting error in returning part of a case. hope here other component where i want to display these data is not required. thank you @JemiSalo

Comment: The error message you're getting tells me you tried to render an object, which usually only happens when rendering a component. Without seeing the component that causes the error, I can only speculate as to what the cause would be. Likely you're rendering something using the values from the state and the render method has a bug in it. Show the code that actually causes the error. From the code you've shown, I can only say that your `mapDispatchToProps` looks funky (Did you forget to wrap the function into an object?), but that almost certainly isn't the cause to your error.

Comment: yes you are correct there is a issue with render @JemiSalo

Comment: Yes, something in Render. I get this error when I make a mistake and accidentally try to do something like `<span>{ myVariable }</span>` where *myVariable* is an object. React doesn't know how to render that. We would have to see what you are trying to render to answer.